# How do I align this flex grid more evenly?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex grid with 4 boxes under "Our Services". Site is located here:

My HTML and CSS code is on the site: https://cleanautoinfo.com/surechoice/#services

I am having a hard time formatting it for StackOverflow because the code is already reformatted and it keeps adding cleartext from the code into stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl+shift+i` or `F12` or `inspect element` tool on most browsers is a powerful tool to debug elements. If you inspect on the website itself there's a utility class for margin-top that's causing the misalignment. See picture below:

[image: the problem]

You can either remove `mt-md-5` on that `div` or add the same utility class to your other `div`.